# NMS: "The object is not an instance of the declared class" error

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit

so I was trying to use Reflection once again to make version dependent classes (Net Mincraft Server aka NMS) work with all versions of the game. I've run into a problem with a method and I can't figure what the error is.

```
    public NPCReflection(UUID id, String name, World world) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.entityId = (int) Math.ceil(Math.random() * 1000) + 2000;

    try {
        Class<?> nmsServerClass = utils.getNMSClass("MinecraftServer");
        Class<?> nmsWorldServerClass = utils.getNMSClass("WorldServer");
        Class<?> obcCraftServerClass = utils.getOBCClass("CraftServer");
        Class<?> obcCraftWorldClass = utils.getOBCClass("CraftWorld");
        Class<?> nmsEntityPlayerClass = utils.getNMSClass("EntityPlayer");
        Class<?> nmsPlayerInteractManager = utils.getNMSClass("PlayerInteractManager");

        Class<?> obcServerClassInstance = obcCraftServerClass.cast(Bukkit.getServer()).getClass();
        Object nmsServerInstance = obcServerClassInstance.getMethod("getServer").invoke(obcServerClassInstance);

        Class<?> obcWorldClassInstance = obcCraftWorldClass.cast(world).getClass();
        Object nmsWorldInstance = obcWorldClassInstance.getMethod("getHandle").invoke(obcWorldClassInstance);

        Constructor<?> entityPlayerConstructor = nmsEntityPlayerClass.getConstructor(nmsServerClass, nmsWorldServerClass, GameProfile.class, nmsPlayerInteractManager);
        Object entityPlayer = entityPlayerConstructor.newInstance(nmsServerInstance, nmsWorldInstance, new GameProfile(id, name), nmsPlayerInteractManager.getConstructor(nmsWorldServerClass).newInstance(nmsWorldInstance));

        utils.setValue(entityPlayer, "a", entityId);

        this.entityPlayer = entityPlayer;
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InstantiationException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

This is the part that is giving me errors.
More precisely this 2 lines.

```
Class<?> obcServerClassInstance = obcCraftServerClass.cast(Bukkit.getServer()).getClass();
  Object nmsServerInstance = obcServerClassInstance.getMethod("getServer").invoke(obcServerClassInstance);
```

And the error is saying that "**The object is not an instance of the declared class**" if I remember correctly (not at the pc ATM).

But bukkit.getServer returns the Server object correctly and I don't know why it does that.

This is the reference without reflection.

```
                Bukkit.getServer().getPluginManager().registerEvents(this, this);

            MinecraftServer nmsServer = ((CraftServer) Bukkit.getServer()).getServer();
            WorldServer nmsWorld = ((CraftWorld) Bukkit.getWorlds().get(0)).getHandle();
            npc = new EntityPlayer(nmsServer, nmsWorld, new GameProfile(UUID.fromString("c793afb5-c4b7-4fdb-a100-b761315913c4"), "PogoStick29"), new PlayerInteractManager(nmsWorld));
```

Answer (score 0):

Standard warning first: Don't use reflection like this. Especially don't use straight-up strings to drive it. Use `enum`s to deliver the strings that your `getXxxClass` methods use.

That said, you are trying with
`Class<?> obcServerClassInstance = obcCraftServerClass.cast(Bukkit.getServer()).getClass();`
first to cast whatever `getServer()` returns to a type represented by `obcCraftServerClass`. That type must be in the class hierarchy of the type returned by `getServer`. Why do you need that particular class? If you did this right, the class represented by `obcCraftServerClass` will be a supertype of that returned by `getServer()`, and you can just use that type without all that messy casting. If the class represented by `obcCraftServerClass` is not a supertype of that returned by `getServer()`, you screwed up.

Do all of this without all that reflection. Really. You shouldn't have to do more reflection than instantiate objects via the types returned by the `utils.getXxxClass`calls, and just assign the resulting instance references to variables of their supertypes. Stop screwing around with all that `Class<?>` garbage.

Your stumbling around with reflection will only lead to unmaintainable tangles, heartache, and broken code. Use object-oriented programming (or better, type-oriented), and you will be much happier.

Comment: The thing is, I want to be able to make thing work with multiple versions of the game. This is the only clean way. Also, have you seen the reference without reflection? I need to cast that class!

Answer (score 0):

I see why you need to cast the class because, well, I'm also using the API. However, you're wrong when you say this is the only clean way. Reflection has many disadvantages: it looks messy, it's hard to follow and it slows down your code (especially when implemented like that). Also, if you're planing to use reflections for accessing NMS fields and methods it's verry likely it will get screwed up in a future version, as Mojang reobfuscates them each revision. I recommend creating an interface and several implementations for it depending on version. This way, you will still have to update your plugin every new revision (only three per major version. For instance, you can only have `1_9_R1`, `1_9_R2` and `1_9_R3`) but you could simply copy/paste your old code used in some older version and re-import the classes to match the current version, and, if needed, change the fields and methods accessed accordingly (you would still have to do that with reflection). 
To make your plugin work on multiple versions at the same time, you should take a look into the maven module system. You can create several independent modules: Base plugin, interface and implementation(s). Whenever a new version pops up, you just add a new implementation module. To check which module you need to use, you get the server version on startup and match it to the right implementation. Mbaxter on the bukkit forums made a really nice tutorial about this: https://bukkit.org/threads/support-multiple-minecraft-versions-with-abstraction-maven.115810/. Hope this helps!